# Array initializing with scanner JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, args

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      args = new String[]{"0 0 1 1"};
   }
}
```

I would like to initialize `args` from console using `Scanner`. Is it possible?

Comment: Wait, what?  No, you don't initialize `args`; it's *already provided* for you.  All you have to do is pass in values on the command line. If you don't want to use the command line, then you *exclusively* use `Scanner`.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: one string value inside your array ?

Comment: Yes, it's "possible".  But why not just make a new array and leave `args` alone?  It's only slightly harder to do than trashing `args` would be.

Answer (score 2):

`args` contains the command-line arguments passed to the Java program upon invocation.

For example if I create `PrintArgs` class like this:

```
public class PrintArgs {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (String s: args) {// loop through args array
            System.out.println(s); // print out every String
        }
    }
}
```

I can now run `PrintArgs` and pass `Strings` to `args`, for example on the command-line I write:

```
$java PrintArgs First Second Third
```

So, it will print out on the console:

```
First
Second
Third
```

Accordingly, you don't need `Scanner` to read from `String[]args` array.

Furthermore, If you want to pass a file path as a String argument to `args`, then use the `Scanner` to read from it, you can do for example:

```
public class ReadFileUsingScanner{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
         try {
              File f = new File(args[0]); // suppose you passed the file path as first String
              Scanner input = new Scanner(f);

              while (input.hasNextLine()) { // loop through every line
                System.out.println(input.nextLine()); // print it out
              }
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you run `ReadFileUsingScanner`for example like this:

```
$java ReadFileUsingScanner someFilePath.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`args` gets initialised by java when you your run the program using `java` command, e.g.: `java Main.class a b c`

So, it's not something we initialise inside the program. Although you can re-initialise the `args` inside `main` method, you should not do it as it (a) loses its previous value and (b) works against the immutability of arguments.

You could probably create a new `array` and ask the user for inputs, e.g.:

```
String[] array = new String[5];
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter "+ array.length + " inputs :" );
for(int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++){
    array[i] = scanner.nextLine();
}
```